# Store clicks on each button separately in json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using `jquery`, `php` and `json` to store and update the clicks on a single download button. It's working flawlessly but now I need to be able to store and update the clicks from multiple download buttons and display them individually.

Can you guys give me a hand with this?
What I have so far is:

> jQuery:

```
$('.download').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Clicks', 'Downloads');
    var redirectUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: "downloads.php",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response = 'success') {
                // The counter file has been updated in the background, but we should update the results on screen to tell the user
                var count = $('.small').html();
                $('.small').html(parseFloat(count) + 1);

                // Then redirect so that file can download
                $("#cover").fadeIn(600);
                $("body").addClass("hidescroll");
                window.location.href = "download/imagins_._ro_free_files_format_icons.rar";
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
});

$.ajax({
    url: "get-downloads.php",
    success: function(data) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $('.small').html(data.count);
    }
});
```

> downloads.php

```
<?php
    $file = "downloads.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $json['count'] = $json['count'] + 1;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
    echo 'success';
?>
```

> get-downloads.php

```
<?php
    $file = "downloads.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

> and the downloads.json

```
{"count":174}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

for example for 3 button

```
<input type='button' name='btn1' class='download'/>
<input type='button' name='btn2' class='download'/>
<input type='button' name='btn3' class='download'/>
```

send name of button to server and show count in different `.smallbtn1`،`.smallbtn2`،`.smallbtn3`

```
$('.download').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Clicks', 'Downloads');
    var redirectUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    //get name of button
    var name= $(this).prop('name');
    //==================
    $.ajax({
        url: "downloads.php",
        data:{buttonName:name},
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response = 'success') {                
                //get count download
                $.ajax({
                    url: "downloadsCount.php",
                    data:{buttonName:name},
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function(response){
                           $('.small'+name).html(response);     
                           $("#cover").fadeIn(600);
                           $("body").addClass("hidescroll");
                           window.location.href = "download/imagins_._ro_free_files_format_icons.rar";                  
                    }                   
               });      
            //===================                    
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

in downloads.php open json file

```
<?php
    $buttonName=$_POST["buttonName"];
    $file = "downloads.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $json['count'.$buttonName] = $json['count'.$buttonName] + 1;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
    echo 'success';
?>
```

downloadsCount.php

```
<?php
    $buttonName=$_POST["buttonName"];
    $file = "downloads.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    echo $json['count'.$buttonName] ; 
?>
```

downloads.json

```
{"countbtn1":0,"countbtn2":0,"countbtn3":0}
```

[this is my test and working for me](http://d-h.st/K2dO)

Comment: This isn't working properly, It triggers the download and fades in the #cover but it's not displaying the click counts.

Comment: you created .smallbtn1 and .smallbtn2 and .smallbtn3 for every button ?

Comment: Yup, in my case it was <button type="button" name="btn1" class="download">download (<span class="smallbtn1"></span>times)</button> and so on for the other two

Comment: Also, your solution is creating a different .json file for every button which isn't quite a good practice to fill the server with .json files even if it worked...if you have, say, 20 buttons...it makes a mess when going in via FTP. I am looking for a way to store them in the same json file.

Comment: Just tried your code and updated it for my needs, it's working fine, the only thing is that I can't update the count on page load, tried this : `$.ajax({
 url: "downloadsCount.php",
 success: function(data) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
  var data = $.parseJSON(data);
 
  $('.small'+name).html(data.count.$buttonName);
 }
}); ` PS: also accepted it since it answers my question. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74034/discussion-between-alin-and-ashkufaraz).

Comment: try like this in page load for show count download `$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "downloadsCount.php",
   data:{buttonName:name},
   method: "POST",
   success: function(response){
    $('.small'+name).html(response);     
   }                   
 });
});`

Comment: I tried this too and it still didn't work when I tried it :) just to be sure it was the same I tried it again and still didn't work :)